# language option in lipics-v2016

Tags: errors, babel, languages

I am trying to prepare a document in the lipics-v2016 template. It can be downloaded from here: https://www.dagstuhl.de/en/publications/lipics/instructions-for-authors/

I tried compiling the lipics-v2016-sample-article.tex file, which is available in the above link. (I use the editor Tex Shop on macOS Sierra.)
I keep getting the error, "you haven't specified the language option".

I don't know how to rectify this.

Comment: Was this resolved? I have this problem too.

Comment: 1. I can not reproduce this 2. the language is specified on the first line as a documenclass option `UKenglish` 3. the current version is now lipics-v2018

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because problem can not be reproduced and package is out of date.